# I need to rename part of the name of multiple files, as per user's indication

Tags: ruby, renaming

Current name of files:

**Empty_test-one.txt**, **Empty_test-two.txt**, **Empty_test-three.txt**

I just want to rename the word **Empty**. My code so far:

```
puts "Indicate new name of files":
new_name = gets.chomp

# Look for the specific files
Dir.glob("*.txt").each do |renaming| 
  # Renaming of files starts, but not on every file
  File.rename(renaming, new_name + ".txt")
```

I'm currently unable to rename each individual file and keep the second part of the file (test-one, test-two, test-three).

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
old_part = "Empty"

puts "Indicate new name of files":
new_name = gets.chomp

# Look for the specific files
Dir.glob("*#{old_part}*.txt").each do |renaming|
  full_new_name = renaming.sub(/\A(.*)#{old_part}(.*)\z/, "\\1#{new_name}\\2")
  File.rename(renaming, full_new_name) 
end
```

What you were missing was to properly build the new name of file, changing `old_name` to `new_name`.

Comment: Thanks mudasobwa for your response. I'm currently having two concerns: Firstly, the extension of one of the files renamed get deleted. Secondly, the files get mixed up after renaming, i.e.: Empty_test-one.txt belongs to Empty_test-two, and the like. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I made a silly typo/mystake. Instead of referring `$1` and `$2` in `sub`, there should be `\1` and `\2`. Please see the answer updated.